# Reputation numbers don't match. Is it a bug?

Tags: support, reputation

Number with blue background doesn't match two green +10s only. Am I missing something here or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: I'd say a reasonably quickly reversed downvote.

Answer (score 5):

If you check your [reputation on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40615/gvs?tab=reputation), on the graph you see a -2 on mar 26.

And 10 + 10 + -2 equals 18.

Comment: Ehm, where do you see that for march 26th?

Comment: On his profile. http://stackoverflow.com/users/40615/gvs?tab=reputation

Comment: *"There were no net reputation changes on this day"* is all I see.

Comment: It is in the graph.

Comment: Ah true. Missed that.

Comment: Thanks! That was hard to find. Why it is only on the graph?

Comment: @GvS If you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom, you'll see that a post of yours was downvoted that day which is now deleted. Weirdly, though, I don't see a corresponding "removed" event for that deletion. Actually, I can't see any "removed" events on your profile, only the regular events that occurred on those posts. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurs when any user give the upvote then +10 and then again any one give the upvote thne +10.

After that any other user will give downvote it will become -18(+10+10-2) then it will show on blue part.

After that downvote remove his vote of downvote then it will not be seen on green part means. There will not be -2 or +2 points.
But in the blue part there will remain -18 only.